# mod_wsgi cannot load mysql

Tags: python, mysql, apache, mod-wsgi, trac

First I will list my environment and status:

Environment:

- System: Mac OS 10.6
- Python: 2.6
- Apache: 2.2
- mod_wsgi: 3.3
- mysql: 5.x
- php: 3.5
- trac:0.12

Status:
I can run trac as alone-server without problem. 
Now I integrate trac to apache, problem come out. mod_wsgi can run normal wsgi page correctly, but cannot load mysql connection. I test it in piece of code, put "**import MySQLdb**" in wsgi page, it still cannot. I also can access trac through apache, but it shows me **Cannot load Python bindings for MySQL**

I refer to the apache log:

```
[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=37060): Target WSGI script /Users/alex/Library/apache2/htdocs/sql.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=37060): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Users/alex/Library/apache2/htdocs/sql.wsgi'.

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/alex/Library/apache2/htdocs/sql.wsgi", line 2, in <module>

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]     import MySQLdb

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1] ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alex/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   Referenced from: /Users/alex/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:44 2011] [error] [client ::1]   Reason: image not found

[Sun Mar 13 13:36:57 2011] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=37061): Target WSGI script
```

This looks like mod_wsgi cannot find libmysqlclient.16.dylib. I encounter similar problem when I install mysqldb for python, so I add export

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/alex/Library/mysql-5.x/lib`

SO python -c "import MySQLdb" can work, but mod_wsgi cannot work.
So I put

```
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Users/alex/Library/mysql-5.x/lib'
```

into trac.ini.
It doesn't work for trac in apache still.

So anyone has this problem before? 
Thanks

Comment: 32-bit vs 64-bit? see http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/#notes

Comment: it is 64-bit, I can run python-mysql without problem. THe problem is the mod_wsgi cannot work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** instead:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: NO, it doesn't work. THe python can import MySQLdb successfully, but the mod_wsgi cannot.

Comment: Just FYI, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is on MacOS what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is on Linux et al.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Apache is running as 64 bit and you are using 32 bit version of MySQL, or Apache is running as 32 bit and you are using 64 bit version of MySQL.

Run the 'file' command on 'libmysqlclient.16.dylib' and it will tell you what architectures it is built for. See similar issues for the actual Python extension at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX#Missing_Code_For_Architecture

You need to get hold of a far MySQL library binary or force Apache to run as same architecture. The linked documentation has some guidelines for what can be done.

Comment: I have checked, both of them are 64 bit executable x86_64.

Comment: Assuming you are running standard Apple Apache/Python amend question with output of 'file' command for /usr/bin/python, /usr/sbin/httpd, /Users/alex/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so and libmysqlclient.16.dylib. Better still, take this over to the official mod_wsgi list. StackOverflow is a crappy place to try and debug problems when no one has an instant answer that works for you.